# How do I change just a part from rdd

Tags: apache-spark, tiff, rdd

I want to modify just the first 100 frames of a tif image which is load loaded via spark and thunder.

I want to assign the percentile_image to the first 100 frames.

```
data = td.images.fromtif(path,'tif',None,None,False,1,10,None,sc,None).cache()

downSampledImage = data.subsample(2)

percentile_image = np.int16(np.percentile(downSampledImage[0:99, :, :], 40, 0))
```

I could not figure out how I can use map function for just a small part.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not super familiar with images in an RDD. But, I'm going to explain some conceptual things about RDDs that might help you understand how to go about your problem.

1. RDDs, unless sorted, have no inherent ordering. Once you put something into a parallelized, distributed data structure, there is no 'first' 100 images or 'last' image. Yeah, you can call `data.first()`,  but really it's just going to the first partition it has, getting the first row it finds, and sending it to the driver. `first` is sort of misleading. It's more like `random`.
2. When you perform an operation on an RDD, you use `map`. `map` will be applied to every single row. Now, you can use `if-else` statements to make sure that the transformation you want to do involving percentiles only applies to a certain set of 100 rows. So you could do

   if (row) meets (condition): 
       np.int16(np.percentile(downSampledImage[0:99, :, :], 40, 0))

However, that requires that those first 100 rows meet some condition so that you can flag them as relevant.

Comment: The problem that there is not a specific flag, they are just the first 100 frames. I did something stupid, I split downSampledImage to the first 100 and the rest then made my modification after that I merged them and did the rest of the job. it should be another way.

Comment: Hm. Is it the first 100 frames of every image (e.g. there are lots of sets of 100 images), or is there only one image total in the whole RDD and you just need the first 100 frames?

Comment: I am curious why this way is not working:
downSampledImage[0:100,:,:].map(lambda x:percentile_image)
why it is not mapping and saving the results in downSampledImage. 
and if I save it to a variable, I will have only the 100 frames which are useless for me. 
it is weird why does the map work vanish and not saved to its variable.

Comment: it is only one image with 810 frames, the first 100 should be the base to make a motion correction for the rest so I should apply this percentile function on them then I took them as a reference to my correction algorithm. so it will correct the whole image ( 810 frames ) depending on the first 100 frames.

Comment: Why are you using Spark / RDDs if you only have 810 rows?

Comment: it is bigger ( almost 3000 frames which equal to 4 GB for each image) I am just trying to write a stable code then I will apply the whole data.